# get flask return statment javascript

Tags: javascript

I am building a program which includes a flask webserver and javascript. I want to get the flask return statement in javascript. e.g:

Python:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Homepage!"
```

Javascript:

```
var url = window.open("flaskwebpage.com");
var url_content = url.content;
console.log(url_content);
```

And the console output would be:

```
Hompage!
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `fetch("flaskwebpage.com").then(r=>r.text()).then(txt=>console.log('text:',txt))`  ... but it wont work unless you have CORS (or its the same server that the js is running on)

Answer (score 0):

`flaskwebpage.com` should be the url of wherever the flask API is being served. If you are running the flask API locally (by simply calling `python app.py` or `flask run`) the url will be something like `http://localhost:5000` (5000 being the default port that the flask app will run on if not otherwise specified).

That is, if that's what you're asking here? You should try to make Stack Overflow questions more specific.